# how to embed the google calculator

Tags: html, embed

some time ago google added a calculator to their websearch. Is there a way to embed it?
or to copy the code to add it to your site?
It is for a google-related thing, so it's allowed to embed it.

this is where i'm talking about: https://www.google.com/search?q=calculator

Comment: You've check that you are deffinately allowed to embed it? Is this stated somewhere? If so, in the same place is probably some documentation on how to embed it.

Comment: ok, I guess that's nowhere stated you're allowed to embed it, but I tried to make a chrome extension with a extension popup with the google calculator.

Comment: what makes you assume you are allowed to embed it or use it in any way?

Comment: because there are lots of other extensions that do the same, for example, there are tons of extensions that embed google tasks in an extension bubble, they are only embedding mail.google.com/tasks/canvas

Answer (score 0):

Well im not sure about embedding their calculator however you can use the google calculator API which allows you to request a calculation and it returns it as json.

http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=1USD=?EUR  This for example requests 1 USD converted to EUR which returns the following result

```
{lhs: "1 U.S. dollar",rhs: "0.811951932 Euros",error: "",icc: true}
```

You may be able to find some other information about the API which may allow other calculations, however as far as I can see there is no official API for the calculator.